# PowerShell: Split String without removing the split-pattern?

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I tried the solution form here but I get the error (my translation) Regex.Split is unknown??
I need to split the line into an string-array but keeping the begin of the lines: "prg=PowerShell°"

my line

```
    $l = "prg=PowerShell°V=2.0°dtd=20120602°user=kjuz°pwd=jhiuz°chk=876876°prg=PowerShell°V=2.0°dtd=20120602°user=kjuz°pwd=jhiuz°chk=876876°prg=PowerShell°V=2.0°dtd=20120602°user=kjuz°pwd=jhiuz°chk=876876°"
    [string]$x = Regex.Split($l, "(prg=PowerShell°)" )
    $x
```

I get:

```
    +         [string]$x = Regex.Split <<<< ($l, "(prg=PowerShell°)" )
            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Regex.Split:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$regex = [regex] '(?=prg=PowerShell°)'
$splitarray = $regex.Split($subject);
```

To split, we are using a zero-width match (i.e., we split without losing characters). To do this, we look ahead to see if the next characters are `prg=PowerShell°` This is what the regex `(?=prg=PowerShell°)` does.

Comment: @gooly: `$splitArray = $subject -split '(?=prg=PowerShell°)'` suffices. You don't have to write C# in PowerShell. As a side note, though, you will get an empty element at the start this way (and the other ways we've seen here so far as well). To avoid that you can hack the regex a bit by explicitly not matching at the start of the string: `(?<!^)(?=prg=PowerShell°)`.